# Только заглавные буквы на кнопке

Tags: android

Задана кнопка

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Start"/>
```

при этом слово на кнопке отображается целиком из заглавных букв: **START**
Вопрос в том, как сделать, чтобы на кнопке было **Start**

Comment: Попробуйте `android:textAllCaps="false"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:textAllCaps="false"

    android:text="Start"/>
```

Я добавил вам его в код.Захотите чтоб сново было заглавными пропишите `true`

Comment: Так вроде если не используешь строку android:textAllCaps по умолчанию стоит "false".